# Before the Global Financial Crisis there used to ferries between Okinawa and Taiwan. How long did the trip take?

Tags: ferries, taiwan, history, okinawa

It seems we can ask historical travel questions here too and a friend just asked me one so I'm posting it.

There are no longer any ferries between Taiwan and Japan but there used to be. The last route shut down on June 6, 2008 as a result of the [Global Financial Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%932008), and never started up again.

Another traveller at my hostel here in Japan just asked me how long the ferry ride used to take. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I found this twelve-year-old post on a Lonely Planet forum:](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/13522636)

> Weekly ferry services operate between the Taiwanese ports of Keelung
>   and Kaohsiung, and the southern Japanese-island of Okinawa. The
>   ferries arrive in and depart from Naha, the capital of Okinawa, often
>   stopping at the Miyako and Ishigaki Islands en route. Fares for **the
>   20-hour journey** range from ¥15,600 to ¥29,300 one-way. Please contact
>   the Arimura Sangyo Company for further information.